# Formatting bibliography in Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word

I want to change the formatting of my **References** page, how would I do it?

Ideally, I want to add breaks at the end of each reference (where the red lines are) without making the content static? Everytime I try to update the field, it goes back to the default (i.e. no spaces).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bibliography and References use the  Normal style. So whatever formatting you are doing for Normal it will apply to your References as well (except for References title, which is based on Heading 1).

You can modify the Normal style to add spaces after each paragraph. Right click on it and select Modify. Then click on Format and set the spacing you want:

[image]

If you want to make this permanent you should create a template that can be used in the future. In case you don't want to alter your Normal style, you can create a new style identical with your Normal style - right click on a paragraph and select Styles > Create a Style

[image]

Name your style (i.e. Old_Normal_Style) and click on Modify to edit the style. This will be your new Normal style.

Now modify your **Normal** style (to look exactly as you want your references to look - To add spacing before or after each reference click on **Format > Paragraph**

Last thing to do is to modify other styles which are based on Normal style and change it to Old_Normal_Style.

Hopefully the explanation is clear. If not, let me know to provide more details

[image]